# backgroundWorker with Process and modal window

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I'm running a process (exe file) and meanwhile I want a 'wait' window to pop up.
Using BGW:

```
public void RunDesign()
{
     BackgroundWorker m_oWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
     m_oWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(m_oWorker_DoWork);
     m_oWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(m_oWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
     m_oWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

     // I want the following pop up window to be shown, while my exe file is running
     wait_debug _wait_debug = new wait_debug();
     Process[] ExeName = Process.GetProcessesByName("AB"); //this is the exe file
     if (ExeName.Length == 1)
     {
           _wait_debug.ShowDialog(); // Show() doesn't work either
           _wait_debug.TopMost = true;
     }
}
```

In the `m_oWorker.DoWork` method I'm running my process with  `p.StartInfo` and it is running fine.
My problem is the wait_debug window is not shown.
Any ideas?

Comment: In the debugger, does it actually reach the line `_wait_debug.ShowDialog();` due to the `if` guard?

Comment: Yes. I put a breakpoint, and it shows the process is not run. Only after I continue running, does the exe fle run.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the main thread does the check `GetProcessesByName` before your thread has had a chance to run the process. Either have the main thread wait on a synchronisation object like `ManualResetEvent` or merely loop around until until `GetProcessesByName` actually returns something.

Here's a simple fix:

```
// NOTE: this loop will block your main GUI thread so it might be
// a good idea not to wait too long by having a timeout mechanism

Process process=null;

do
{
    Thread.Sleep(0);  // be nice to CPU

    Process[] items = Process.GetProcessesByName("AB"); //this is the exe file
    if (items.Length == 1)
    {
        process = items[0];
    }

    // break if taking too long
}
while (process == null);

// if process is still null then we timed out.  handle appropriately

_wait_debug.ShowDialog(); // Show() doesn't work either
_wait_debug.TopMost = true;
```

You can verify you existing condition in the debugger - you'll find that it does not actually reach the line `_wait_debug.ShowDialog();` due to the `if` guard.  Your main thread beat the worker thread to the punch by looking for a process that had not started yet.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work. First the ShowDialog lines should be inside the do statement, right? bcause I want to show them as long as the process running. Anyway, ShowDialog does work but is Modal AND it keeps coming over and over even if process finished (because the process is null after it had finished). Secondly, if I use Show(), which is Modaless,  it get stucked, and this I do not understand at all.

Comment: _"should be inside the do statement, right?"_ - wrong. In that case you would use `Show`.  You can close the window in  your background workers completed event handler.  As for the rest of your comment I have no idea what you are talking about